# Why autoref lets text ignore wrapfigure

Tags: hyperref, texlive, ubuntu, wrapfigure

I just ran into a problem concerning `autoref` in combination with the `wrapfigure` environment of the `wrapfig` package.

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{}
\end{wrapfigure}

\autoref{ref} % arbitrary reference
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

The result looks like:

```
               ######################
REFtextextextex|extextextextextext  |
textextextextex|extextextextextext  |
textextextextex|...                 |
               |                    |
               |      PICTURE       |
               ######################
```

When I use ref instead of `autoref` the text is correctly aligned beside the `wrapfig`.
EDIT: Both *pdflatex* and *texi2pdf* produce this result.
Any ideas?

**SOLVED**: Updating from TeX Live 2009 (default for Ubuntu 10.04 at the moment) to TeX Live 2012 solved the problem.

Old file list:

```
[...]
wrapfig.sty    2003/01/31  v 3.6
hyperref.sty    2009/10/09 v6.79a Hypertext links for LaTeX
[...]
```

Note the old version of `hyperref`.
Under Ubuntu TeX Live can be upgraded by adding the repository `ppa:texlive-backports/ppa` and calling `apt-get upgrade`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).

Comment: Your example works fine for me.

Comment: As @MarcoDaniel says, the example works fine. However, I note that your don't have a `\label` for the `\autoref`, which will alter the amount of text involved. (I'd also suggest using `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}` to make the MWE compilable without edits.)

Comment: @JosephWright I added the demo option, thanks. A valid label does not change the situation, so I removed it for the sake of minimalism.

Comment: @JD3 I've tried your example with both TeX Live 2012 and 2013 (pretest), and have no issues. Could you (1) edit in a picture showing the output you get for the MWE and (2) add `\listfiles` to the MWE and edit in the resulting `File list` from your `.log` file?

Comment: @JosephWright Well, TeX Live 2009 (!) produces this result. My Ubuntu installation (10.04) used (until now) this old version.

Comment: @JD3 On that basis, I will close as 'too localized' (the 'standing policy' is that issues caused by old versions of packages are closed in this way).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot reproduce the problem (`pdflatex`, `latex` + `dvips` + `ps2pdf`, `xelatex`):

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}E=mc^2\label{ref}\end{equation}

\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{dummypic}
\end{wrapfigure}

\autoref{ref} % arbitrary reference
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

From the version list:

> ```
>  *File List*
> [...]
>  wrapfig.sty    2003/01/31  v 3.6
> hyperref.sty    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hypertext links for LaTeX
> [...]
> ```